# wamp -> php only loads in index.php not in other file names

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wamp64

So I've had this problem a while that my php will only execute in
index.php but not in files like: login.php this will just show plain
code. I am not using short tags. I recently reïnstalled wamp and it's
running on windows 10 home 64x specific version of

```
wamp: 3.1.0 wamp64
php: 5.6.31
```

module is loaded in apache and .php is reggistered as php file in
httpd.conf here is an example of an [index.php](http://www.pixelnetwork.be/stack/index.php) and here is an
example of [login.php](http://www.pixelnetwork.be/stack/login.php) I hope someone is able to help me :)
I've already looked at other posts and tried them but none worked.
There is nothing wrong with the 2 files. But only 1 loads.

Comment: what is url for login.php..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Could you try something like test.php, to make sure it isn't some kind of security thing?

Comment: Why is it a duplicate? His index.php does work.

Comment: the 2 test links are at the bottom of the post